# Unidac (delphi) macro issue

Tags: delphi, unidac

I have query:

```sql
select &macro1 from table1
where &macro2
```

delphi code:

```pascal
macrobyname('macro1').value := 'field1 as test,field2';
macrobyname('macro2').value := 'test=1';
```

i got an error like this:

```
Unknown column test in where clouse
```

question 2)

showmessage(sql.text); Result is "select &macro1 from table1 where &macro2"
 but I expect "select field1 as test,field2 from table1 where test=1"

how  can i get sql.text after macro replacing.

(Excuse me for bad english).

best regards,
nouri

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what database you are using but those that I have used (SQL Server and Sybase) don't allow field aliases to be used in the where clause. So you would have to say:

```
macrobyname('macro2').value := 'field1=1';
```

Comment: Yes , i find solution , i have to use having clouse instead of where. actually I know that but in real query , macro1 is ",(select sum(filed1) from table2 where table2.code=table1.code) as test", BTW I have to use having. thank for response.

Answer (score 1):

Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.
Сolumn alias can be used in an ORDER BY clause, but it cannot be used in a WHERE, GROUP BY, or HAVING clause.